# JavaScript or PHP based WYSIWYG vector based image editor

Tags: php, javascript, web-applications, wysiwyg

For a PHP based site of a client, I'm looking for a vector based image editor that allows:

- end user creation of vectored images consisting of objects
- supports upload of bitmap images to be used as objects inside the vector image
- supports adding text objects to add to the vector image, and change properties (font name, font style, font size) of the text objects
- preferably supports layering or grouping of objects inside the vector image
- integrates nicely with a PHP based site (so a PHP or JavaScript library is preferred)
- can store the vector image in SVG, EPS or PDF

Both commercial and FOSS solutions are OK.

Any idea where to find such a library?

--jeroen

Comment: Some years ago I searched for something like this and found some solutions. IIRC they were Flash based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [SVG-edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG-edit) is one.

Comment: It works well in Chrome, FireFox and Safari out of the box. For Internet Explorer 6-8, it needs the Chrome Frame Plugin (http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

Answer (score 0):

I've done some crawling for such tools as well in Open Source.

I've found pieces, with some extra efforts you can maybe make some glue or recode with inspiration:

Nice 'imprecise-line-drawing' editor, but fonts are handed via ajax calls:
http://zwibbler.com/ (png/pdf/svg save)

A library to handle fonts in javascript, need some work to really use it as an external lib
http://typeface.neocracy.org/ and check http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ & http://www.netzgesta.de/dev/text/ as well.

Comment: Zwibbler starts at $2999! That's insane.

Comment: @TheStoryCoder maybe, did not check the marketing parts, and this post was in 2011, things may have changed.